# How can i group data based on range of values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have data like

```
[312.281,
 370.401,
 254.245,
 272.256,
 312.325,
 286.243,
 271.231,  ...]
```

then I want to group them by the range of value by

```
for i in data:
    if i in range(200,300):
        data_200_300.append(i)
    elif i in range(300,400):
        data_300_400.append(i)
```

it not working, what code should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of such values and the possibility to import `numpy`, there is a faster option than a string of if-conditions or lambda-filter. It's using logical indexing:

```
def indexingversion(data, bin_start, bin_end, bin_step):
    x = np.array(data)
    bin_edges = np.arange(bin_start, bin_end + bin_step, bin_step)
    bin_number = bin_edges.size - 1
    cond = np.zeros((x.size, bin_number), dtype=bool)
    for i in range(bin_number):
        cond[:, i] = np.logical_and(bin_edges[i] < x,
                                    x < bin_edges[i+1])
    return [list(x[cond[:, i]]) for i in range(bin_number)]
```

I have put all solutions so far and my version in their own function and ran them all at once, using a line profiler ([rkern/line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler)).
The last line proofs that all three outputs are identical (which costs my version a bit, since I have to convert into numpy arrays at the start and back in the end).

My version and the lambda version have the additional advantage that you can also group them in other bins, where you would have to rewrite the `if`-statements in the first solution.

```
import numpy as np

def forloop(x):
    data_200_300 = []
    data_300_400 = []
    for i in x:
        if 200 < i < 300:
            data_200_300.append(i)
        elif 300 < i < 400:
            data_300_400.append(i)
    return [data_200_300, data_300_400]


def lambdaversion(data, bin_start, bin_end, bin_step):
    filtered_data = []
    for i in range(bin_start,bin_end,bin_step):
        filtered_data.append( filter(lambda x: i < x < i+bin_step, data) )
    return filtered_data


def indexingversion(data, bin_start, bin_end, bin_step):
    x = np.array(data)
    bin_edges = np.arange(bin_start, bin_end + bin_step, bin_step)
    bin_number = bin_edges.size - 1
    cond = np.zeros((x.size, bin_number), dtype=bool)
    for i in range(bin_number):
        cond[:, i] = np.logical_and(bin_edges[i] < x,
                                    x < bin_edges[i+1])
    return [list(x[cond[:, i]]) for i in range(bin_number)]


#@profile
def run_all():
    n = 100000
    x = np.random.random_integers(200, 400, n) + np.random.ranf(n)
    bin_start = 200
    bin_end = 400
    bin_step = 100
    a = forloop(x)
    b = lambdaversion(x, bin_start, bin_end, bin_step)
    c = indexingversion(x, bin_start, bin_end, bin_step)
    print('All the same? - ' + str(a == b == c))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_all()
```

Profiling output:

```
All the same? - True
Wrote profile results to bla.py.lprof
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.580098 s
File: bla.py
Function: run_all at line 32

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    32                                           @profile
    33                                           def run_all():
    34         1            1      1.0      0.0      n = 100000
    35         1         3311   3311.0      0.6      x = np.random.random_integers(200, 400, n) + np.random.ranf(n)
    36         1            2      2.0      0.0      bin_start = 200
    37         1            1      1.0      0.0      bin_end = 400
    38         1            0      0.0      0.0      bin_step = 100
    39         1       263073 263073.0     45.3      a = forloop(x)
    40         1       301819 301819.0     52.0      b = lambdaversion(x, bin_start, bin_end, bin_step)
    41         1         7514   7514.0      1.3      c = indexingversion(x, bin_start, bin_end, bin_step)
    42         1         4377   4377.0      0.8      print('All the same? - ' + str(a == b == c))
```

As you can see (in the `Time` or `% Time` column), the numpy-indexing is about a factor of 40 or 50 times faster, at least for 100,000 numbers. However, for very small numbers of values it's slower (on my machine it starts be faster at about 40 values).

Answer (score 3):

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) returns a list of integers between two numbers while your data contains floating point numbers. You can directly use [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) using `>` and `<` for this:

```
for i in data:
    if 200 < i < 300:
        data_200_300.append(i)
    elif 300 < i < 400:
        data_300_400.append(i)
```

If you want some matches to be inclusive, you can use `<=` as well.

Comment: what if I want to group in the column like
df = [ id, v1, v2, v3
         1, 12, 32, 23
         2, 65, 45, 22
         3, 55, 34, 76
         ...]

if i want to group based on V3 colunn, what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

@AKS answered it right as an alternative you can also try it with **lambda expressions** something like this.

```
result = filter(lambda x: 200 < x < 300, data)
```

and you can use this like it to process your data

```
filtered_data = []
for i in range(200,400,100):
    filtered_data.append( filter(lambda x: i < x < i+100, data) )

>>> filtered_data
[[254.245, 272.256, 286.243, 271.231], [312.281, 370.401, 312.325]]
```